# useRef for showing the count of characters inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

Having the following component:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface TexareaProps extends React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
  maxLength?: number;
  id: string;
}

export const Textarea = React.forwardRef(
  (
    { id = 'my-id', maxLength = 200, ...props }: TexareaProps,
    ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    return (
      <div className='relative flex flex-col'>
        <textarea id={id} maxLength={maxLength} {...props}></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default Textarea;
```

It returns a textarea where a user can write up to 200 characters. My aim is to show somewhere the current count of written characters, so in order to do that the component must use `useRef` hook to access the textarea.

In plain JS it would be like:

```
const toCheck = document.getElementById('my-id');
console.log(toCheck.value.length); // this will log the current count of written chars
```

But how can it be done with useRef?

Comment: Pass in a `value` prop (which will be used through state in most cases) and then just use `value.length`. And also don't forget to set `value` as a child to `textarea`: `< textarea>{props.value}</textarea>`

Comment: can you make it an answer please?

Comment: [Codesandbox example of what I meant](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-tdd-08tdh?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: it works on your example but I cannot transform it to be only one component, in your example you're sending props from the App. Is it possible to make it an internal functionality of the component? I've tried to modify your code without success

Answer (score 2):

pass ref to textarea

```
<textarea ref={ref} id={id} maxLength={maxLength}{...props}></textarea>
```

and you can use component `Textarea` like this

```
const textAreaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>()

console.log(textAreaRef.current?.value.length)

return <Textarea ref={textAreaRef} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
import React from "react";

export interface TexareaProps
  extends React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
  maxLength?: number;
  id: string;
}

export const Textarea = React.forwardRef(
  (
    { id = "my-id", maxLength = 200, ...props }: TexareaProps,
    ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    return (
      <div className="relative flex flex-col">
        <textarea {...props} ref={ref} id={id} maxLength={maxLength}></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default Textarea;
```

and then in the parent, you can show the number of character

```
const textAreaRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  if (textAreaRef.current) {
    console.log(textAreaRef.current.value.length);
  }
}, [textAreaRef]);
```